# Ошибка при компиляции проекта в unity. mainTemplate.gradle file is using the old aaptOptions

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Текст ошибки.

> mainTemplate.gradle file is using the old aaptOptions noCompress property definition which does not include types defined by unityStreamingAssets constant.`

Помогите решить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: посмотрите на [этот](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1802208/build-error-27.html) ответ

Comment: В вашем вопросе нет вопроса